# Kubernetes pod design - Share PHP source code among multiple pods /containers during horizontal scaling

Tags: php, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I am designing a kubernetes pod for web application developed in PHP. I have two containers in the pod - one for php-fpm and another ngninx. NXIGNX container is just a http server redirects all request to php-fpm container. It doesnt serve static resources. I could easily develop this pod. However I also have requirement of inserting large amount of data in database while building the PHP application which is also part of the php docker container. Because of this Scaling of the application takes few minutes. To avoid that I have split this pod into two pods. One pod installs the php application and another runs the php. In the 1st pod I have two containers - one is the init container which copies all files from host into a persistent volume and second one the installer which build the php application including running database script. This pod works perfectly. The second one contain two containers one is php-fpm docker container and another nginx docker container. The php-fpm container point the persistent volume created in 1st pod for its php code.

And second pod can easily scaled horizontally. Can anyone tell me if the pod design has any issues?

Comment: What do you mean with "any issues"? 
You mean security issues? performance issues?
Could you please be more specific with your question or share your yaml config so we can review it in depth?

Comment: I dont  see any performance or security issues. But i see a problem with php-fpm process. During horizontal scaling multiple fpm-php process will be accessing the  PHP code in mounted persistence volume(in my case its a google filestore)